# How to write a library in ROS?

Tags: ros, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to write my own ros library.
Just a ROS package containing a .hpp, a .cpp and the compiled library of the cpp.

I put the cpp inside the src folder, the hpp into the include directory and added the add_library command to the CMakeLists.txt, and the shared object file is created. But now I want to get this library used by another package. I added the library package to its manifest.xml. And it does not find the header file of the library package. I can make it link the library with multiple commands in the CMakeLists but then I still do not get the header file.

I found a tutorial on github:
[Tutorial](https://github.com/uscrs-art/uscrs-art/wiki/ROS-How-Do-I%3A-Create-My-Own-ROS-Library)

It says that something needs to be added to the manifest.xml, but unfortunately the line telling that is missing. (The line was removed because of the tags I guess)

```
I guessed it might be the <export> tag like this:
 <export>
    <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include/ -I${prefix}/include/NameOfLib" lflags="-L${prefix}/lib -Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib -lNameOfLib"/> 
  </export>
```

But it doesn't work.

Can anybody help me with that?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29058/how-to-write-a-library-in-ros?/) by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1376 on 2012-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got it!
Must be related to old compilation data, I am using the cmake extensions for Eclipse and I deleted CMakeCache.txt cmake_install.cmake and the directory CMakeFiles and recompiled everything, now it seems to work.

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2012-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you also set set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib) in your CMakeLists.txt?

Of course in the Manifest.xml file of the other package you want to use this library you add somethings like  so it goes and grabs that  tag.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-03-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2012-03-04**:
I created the package with roscreate-pkg, so yes it's set. I also did the same with the other package referencing the library package in the manifest, but it still does not work.